# How to compare two for loop index number in Django template?

Tags: python-3.x, nested-for-loop

I want to implement in django template just like this

```
for i in range(0,10):
     for j in range(0,10):
       if(i.index == j.index):
          print(j)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed my problem using this .Thanks.

```
{% if forloop.counter == forloop.parentloop.counter %}
```